# Binding Data from tutorial example

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm pretty new to d3 and have been following this tutorial: http://christopheviau.com/d3_tutorial/

I'm stuck on the 'Binding Data' example - it's pretty simple but the code just won't produce anything. I've poked around here and haven't found the question listed so I thought I'd ask away.

Here's the code:

```
var dataset = [],
    i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    dataset.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 100));
}

var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 75);

sampleSVG.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("height", 40)
    .attr("width", 75)
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return i * 80
    })
    .attr("y", 20);
```

Other examples on the site work fine.

Thanks in advance - any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the code listed in the tutorial is incorrect. The svg element "circle" is specified by three attributes, "cx", x-axis coordinate of the center of the circle, "cy", y-axis coordinate of the center of the circle, and "r", the radius of the circle. I got this information from the w3 specification for an [SVG circle](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#CircleElement).

I would recommend inspecting the JavaScript in the tutorial page to help iron out any other inconsistencies. Here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var dataset = [],
      i = 0;

  for(i=0; i<5; i++){
     dataset.push(Math.round(Math.random()*100));
   }        

   var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz5")
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", 400)
     .attr("height", 100);

   sampleSVG.selectAll("circle")
     .data(dataset)
     .enter().append("circle")
     .style("stroke", "gray")
     .style("fill", "white")
     .attr("r", 40)
     .attr("cx", function(d, i){return i*80+40})
     .attr("cy", 50)
     .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
     .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");})
     .on("mousedown", animateFirstStep);

   function animateFirstStep(){
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .delay(0)
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("r", 10)
        .each("end", animateSecondStep);
    };

    function animateSecondStep(){
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("r", 40);
    };
</script>
```

I also created a JSFiddle which you can utilize to get the basic idea that the author of the tutorial is trying to convey, with respect to utilizing d3.js data, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dNRNq/).

Answer (score 0):

svg circles use cx, cy, and r - not x, y, height, and width. I've correct the example code below:

```
var dataset = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    dataset.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 100));
}

var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 400);

sampleSVG.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
        return i * 80 + 10;
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d, i) {
        return  d;
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q3P4v/7/

MDN on svg circles: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Element/circle